# Grouping repeated fields in BQ

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the following table where "product" is a repeated field.

[image]

How can I group by "id" and merge the repeated field to sum the quantities so the output looks like this.

[image]

Trying to find an elegant solution that does not unnest.

Comment: unnest is the intended way to work with arrays - [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below

```
select id, array(
  select as struct sku, sum(quantity) quantity
  from t.product
  group by sku
  ) product
from (
  select id, array_concat_agg(product) product
  from your_table
  group by id
) t
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Excellent. That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!